# Oneplus One only working in 2G, loses carrier with 3G/4G

Tags: oneplus-one

Unless I select 2G as the "preferred network type", my oneplus one disconnects from the carrier. Not just the data connection, even the phone one.

My operator is I WIND.

It's not a SIM problem, since that same SIM works fine on my old phone, and it's not a "it's not inserted well" problem, since if I select 2G it works.

What can I do to investigate the problem? Is this operator not supported or is the phone defective, or maybe some strange misconfiguration? On the official site they claim it is supported "with limited LTE", but it doesn't work with 3G either, while I obviously assumed it did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating to 4.4.4 solved the problem (it came with 4.4.2 installed).

Comment: Hey, don't forget to accept this as the answer, as other users may have this problem and this will (hopefully) help them. Glad you got it fixed! (Have some +1s)

Comment: @RossC sure, but it says I can't accept it in the first two days, quite handy!

Comment: I guess that is the risk you (and I) take with semi-community developed software

Answer (score 1):

My OPO works fine with 3g and 4g, have you checked the 4g bands are compatible (there is a list on OPO website, and there should be one on I winds).

Are you sure it is losing connection, not just the signal icon showing a drop when switching between sources.

For 3g have you tried restarting (and would you normally get coverage in the area), if so you could try another sim (a friends on a different network) see if it works, if it doesn't it may be a hardware fault.

If another network works and the network bands say your network should work I would contact your network and if they can't help switch network (which you have the freedom of doing, thanks to buying upfront).

If other networks don't work I would recommend reflashing cm11s, especially the radio.IMG, as that will reset the 3g/4g firmware.

If all else fails, contact One plus.

Comment: It's really losing the carrier, I also get the warning message "No service" and doesn't ever come back up.

Comment: [Officially](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/carrier-compatibility-list.70220/) it is supported: "Wind (Partial LTE)" "-- --- (Partial LTE) means 3G is fully supported, and one or more LTE bands is not supported."

Comment: Ok, have a go at the other things i ve suggested